# Capturing bitmaps causing Out Of Memory exception

Tags: .net, vb.net, timer, bitmap, screenshot

**The Problem**

I am currently trying to create an application that would create a gif/video (not decided yet) of a users screen as they replicate an issue on their computer. This obviously means that I need to create a screenshot periodically via a timer.

The problem is that after 25 seconds (always 25 seconds), I get an error saying that the system is out of memory.

```
Exception thrown: 'System.OutOfMemoryException' in System.Drawing.dll

Additional information: Out of memory.
```

**My Code**

Below is the code that is in the Timer Tick event:

```
Private DebugVid As New List(Of IntPtr)

Private Sub tmrDebug_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tmrDebug.Tick

    Dim CurrentScreen As Screen = Screen.PrimaryScreen
    For Each SCR As Screen In Screen.AllScreens
        If SCR.Bounds.Contains(MousePosition) Then
            CurrentScreen = SCR
        End If
    Next

    Using ScreenGrab As New Bitmap(CurrentScreen.Bounds.Width, CurrentScreen.Bounds.Height)
        Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(ScreenGrab)
            g.CopyFromScreen(New Point(CurrentScreen.Bounds.X, CurrentScreen.Bounds.Y), New Point(0, 0), ScreenGrab.Size)
            g.DrawImage(My.Resources.MyCursor, New Point(MousePosition.X - CurrentScreen.Bounds.X, MousePosition.Y))
        End Using
        DebugVid.Add(ScreenGrab.GetHbitmap())
    End Using

    GC.Collect()
End Sub
```

The first section just defines which screen the cursor is on so I knows which screen to create the bitmap of.

The second section creates the bitmap, applies a screenshot to it, draws a cursor at the mouse position, and then finally stores the integer pointer in a list.

Once the user has clicked a button to stop the recording, it converts it into a gif (at the moment).

The part of the code that is throwing an exception is the following line:

```
DebugVid.Add(ScreenGrab.GetHbitmap())
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: 25 seconds, how many frames per second? What's image size? Do the math and you will probably understand why you're running out of memory. You'd better save files somewhere and build GIF with them, just don't keep them in memory. BTW why do you need HBITMAP?

Comment: This is kind of my first go at something like this so I have bit and pieces from all around the web, hence the HBITMAP. I do understand that storing images is a hefty task so any alternatives to what I am currently trying is more than welcome. The timer runs twice a second, the image size is the resolution of my screen which is currently 1680x1050

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's potentially a lot of unmanaged GDI handles and bitmap data to keep in memory.  I wouldn't be surprised at all if, after 25 seconds, you depleated the available handles, or even just the available process memory.  You may want to consider saving each frame out to disk as it is recorded.  Then when recording is done, processes the individual images in to a gif.

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724291(v=vs.85).aspx) the number of GDI handles available to a process can range from 256 to 65536 depending on the operating system and configuration.  Each screenshot you are taking is using up *at least* one handle, and many more are being used by your application and the .net framework.

Comment: I have literally just tried your suggestion and saved the Base 64 string versions of the screenshots in a text file instead of storing it in memory. The file hit 8GB in about a minute and a half so not exactly viable. Is there a better way to store it?

Comment: Base 64 encoding will actually make your files LARGER.  I'd recommend saving each frame as a `png`.  It should give you significant compression without loss of quality.  Also, at 8GB on disk, that certainly explains why you were running out of memory.

Comment: About 100MB in 1 minute, I think that is the best I am going to get so thank you very much. I just need to remember to delete the PNGs when the GIF is created!